# Is there a way to track loading of individual resources in an uiwebview for ios

Tags: ios, resources, uiwebview, tracking

when a UIWebView tries to load a webpage, is there a way to track individual resources like images, js, css being loaded into webview. Basically i am looking for callbacks. Are there callbacks in ios which get fired say when a request for an image is sent out and another callback which is fired when image is downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `NSURLCache` you will get callbacks for each file that downloads with the webpage.

Basically you need to subclass the `NSURLCache` class and set it as shared cache like this :

```
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
```

In your subclass you will need to override the `- (NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponseForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` method to add your behavior. This will get called for each resource loaded in the webpage.

You can take a look at the Apple Sample code project [URL CacheInfo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CacheInfo-MacOSX/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007751) or at the [SDURLCache](https://github.com/steipete/SDURLCache) project on github that extend the default `NSURLCache` behavior.