# IOS intercept webview load and save webpage resources to disk

Tags: ios, webview, resources, save, nsurlcache

I have read that you can track individual resources being downloaded for use in loading a webview, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527682/is-there-a-way-to-track-loading-of-individual-resources-in-an-uiwebview-for-ios). What I want to do is intercept and save each resource to file. Then, if the user wants to save the webpage, I will take the saved resources and html and store them in a permanent location. But I am a newbie and don't know how to set this up. Can someone help?

Comment: Duplicate question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162295/library-for-caching-web-pages-on-iphone

Answer (score -1):

Look at URLProtocol subclassing for caching the entire network traffic, plus there are too many libraries for this.

[Let me google it for you](http://goo.gl/M2xtY)